# Calculating the fitted values for a polynomial. Is a summation needed? How to make general purpose?

Tags: r, sum

I want to calculate the fitted value for a polynomial manually.

```r
# Here is an example for poly(5):

x <- runif(n = 50, min = 1, max = 10)
y <- runif(n = 50, min = 10, max = 20)
f <- lm(y ~ poly(x, 5, raw=TRUE), na.action=na.exclude)

fit <- f$coeff[1] + f$coeff[2]*x + f$coeff[3]*x^2 + f$coeff[4]*x^3 + 
  f$coeff[5]*x^4 + 
  f$coeff[6]*x^5
```

I would like to calculate 'fit' manually (not using the predict() function, which I know I could use), but I would also like to be able to use the sum-function that would automatically adjust the equation by one more term when the power of the polynomial increases.

Eventually, I would like to iterate through different power polynomials without adjusting the above equation for 'fit' every time.

[image]

Comment: Could you edit the question title? I find it misleading, it's not a question on summations, its' about fitted polynomials. The summation part is a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the rules of matrix multiplication.
Append a column of ones if you fit a model with intercept (this is the question's case) and multiply.
The result of a matrix multiply is a matrix so I coerce to vector in order to compare the two results.
Note the use of extractor function `coef`, the recommended way.

```
fit2 <- cbind(1, poly(x, 5, raw=TRUE)) %*% coef(f)
identical(fit, as.vector(fit2))
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Sorry, can't seem to change the title anymore.

Comment: @Stata_user I could, see if you agree. If not, propose a title that you believe describes the question and I will edit again.

Comment: Thanks! That will do.